# ubuntu apache2 cgi output buffering

Tags: perl, apache, ubuntu, buffering

I'm having problems with apache2 on Ubuntu ( 11.04 and 12.04 ) buffering all cgi output until the script terminates. If I run the same script on Centos/rhel 6.2 apache2, it runs normally.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$|=1;
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";

print "hi..";
sleep 1;
print "hi..";
sleep 1;
print "hi..";
sleep 1;
```

I have verified that mod_deflate is disabled.

Also, it's NOT just a perl thing, the same cgi script written in bash behaves the same on Ubuntu VS centos/rhel.

Comment: What happens when apache runs your script?

Comment: everything gets printed when the script completes. like if buffering is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem on Solaris 10, but found out, that is was actually not a problem of apache but instead of the web browser (firefox 15.0.1).
(I could verify this with `telnet webserver 80` and speaking plain HTML, the response showed that the output was indeed not buffered)

I could solve this for firefox by also printing a header with a Content-Type meta tag:

```
print<<'_EOF_';
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
_EOF_
```

Explorer however still seems to wait for all data before rendering the page, other browsers I do not have available.

Comment: Thanks, after I changed the Content type statement to:
print "Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n"; it worked. using both firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The debian/ubuntu ( and solaris too obviously )  apache package stock configs doesn't specify the character set like on Redhat. The real solution is to define simply it.

on ubuntu, add the following to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Wihtout it, the browser caches the output of the cgi script.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been searching for days for this answer with no luck.  I still have an issue though, this only appears to work with Firefox and IE, Chrome is still buffering the output, also I tried running an "nph" script like this and the output of that is still buffered.  Do you have any idea what could be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

For me it helps to disable the deflate module:

```
sudo a2dismod deflate
```